Consulta de sql
estoy intentando combinar (SUMAR) una consulta de sql y llevo un buen rato pero estoy atascado y bloqueado y ya no se como formularlo:
Tengo esta consulta:

    SELECT 
    FORMAT(HoraInicioLinea, 'yyyy/MM/dd') as Fecha,
    linea,
    Tarifa,
    COUNT(*) as totalTarifa,
    NombreTarifa,
    NombreTitulo,
    DescTipoOperacion
FROM GADIMON_FCS.dbo.vw_operaciones
WHERE 
    HoraInicioLiquidacion >= '20240401 05:00' 
    AND HoraFinalLiquidacion <= '20240402 04:59'
    AND DescTipoOperacion != 'Recarga'
    AND DescTipoOperacion != 'RegularizarSaldo'
    AND tarifa in (23,26)
    --and linea = 11
GROUP BY
    linea,
    Tarifa,
    NombreTarifa,
    NombreTitulo,
    DescTipoOperacion,
    FORMAT(HoraInicioLinea, 'yyyy/MM/dd')
ORDER BY 
    linea ASC;

Y estoy intentando hacer que me combine dos tarifas (23 y 26), aquí unos resultados de la consulta:
1   2024/04/01  11  23  44  PASE ESP.1  NULL    Billete
2   2024/04/01  11  26  164 MENOR 4AÑO  NULL    Billete
3   2024/04/01  12  23  10  PASE ESP.1  NULL    Billete
4   2024/04/01  12  26  109 MENOR 4AÑO  NULL    Billete
5   2024/04/01  13  23  4   PASE ESP.1  NULL    Billete
6   2024/04/01  13  26  51  MENOR 4AÑO  NULL    Billete

Estos registro siguen, lo he intentado de muchas formas pero ahora mismo estoy bloqueado.
Lo que quiero conseguir es que me sume las líneas 23 y 26 en una combinada (23+26)
Gracias de antemano.

He agrupado todos los campos que necesito sumar por si alguien consigue ver la forma que debo conseguirlo, yo llevo desde ayer dándole vueltas y no lo consigo:
SELECT 
    FORMAT(HoraInicioLinea, 'yyyy/MM/dd') as Fecha,
    linea,
    CASE 
        WHEN tarifa = 23 THEN 'Tarifa Gratuita'  
        WHEN tarifa = 26 THEN 'Tarifa Gratuita' 
        WHEN tarifa = 0 and NombreTitulo = 'CONY. JUB.' THEN  'Tarifa Gratuita'
        WHEN tarifa = 0 and NombreTitulo = 'EMPLEADO' THEN  'Tarifa Gratuita'
        WHEN tarifa = 0 and NombreTitulo = 'FAMILIAR' THEN  'Tarifa Gratuita'
        WHEN tarifa = 0 and NombreTitulo = 'PENSIONISTA' THEN  'Tarifa Gratuita'
        ELSE CAST(tarifa AS VARCHAR(10))  
    END AS Tarifa,
    SUM(tipoOperacion) as totalTarifa,
    NombreTarifa,
    NombreTitulo,
    DescTipoOperacion
FROM GADIMON_FCS.dbo.vw_operaciones
WHERE 
    HoraInicioLiquidacion >= '20240401 05:00' 
    AND HoraFinalLiquidacion <= '20240402 04:59'
    AND DescTipoOperacion != 'Recarga'
    AND DescTipoOperacion != 'RegularizarSaldo'
GROUP BY
    FORMAT(HoraInicioLinea, 'yyyy/MM/dd'),
    linea,
    CASE 
        WHEN tarifa = 23 THEN 'Tarifa Gratuita'  
        WHEN tarifa = 26 THEN 'Tarifa Gratuita' 
        WHEN tarifa = 0 and NombreTitulo = 'CONY. JUB.' THEN  'Tarifa Gratuita'
        WHEN tarifa = 0 and NombreTitulo = 'EMPLEADO' THEN  'Tarifa Gratuita'
        WHEN tarifa = 0 and NombreTitulo = 'FAMILIAR' THEN  'Tarifa Gratuita'
        WHEN tarifa = 0 and NombreTitulo = 'PENSIONISTA' THEN  'Tarifa Gratuita'
        ELSE CAST(tarifa AS VARCHAR(10))
    END,
    NombreTarifa,
    NombreTitulo,
    DescTipoOperacion
ORDER BY 
    linea ASC;

Y este es el resultado:
1   2024/04/01  11  0   3   -   BONOBUS ORD.    Validación(entrada)
2   2024/04/01  11  0   10  -   MAYOR 65 4ANIOS Validación(entrada)
3   2024/04/01  11  0   3   -   MAYOR 65 CADIZ  Validación(entrada)
4   2024/04/01  11  0   59  -   Mayor 65años    Validación(entrada)
5   2024/04/01  11  0   79  -   TARJETA JOVEN CADIZ Validación(entrada)
6   2024/04/01  11  4   -1  ORD.CADIZ   NULL    Anul.Billete
7   2024/04/01  11  4   1443    ORD.CADIZ   NULL    Billete
8   2024/04/01  11  91  25  BONO O CAD  BONOBUS ORD. CADIZ  Anul.Validación
9   2024/04/01  11  91  4826    BONO O CAD  BONOBUS ORD. CADIZ  Transbordo(entrada)
10  2024/04/01  11  91  10918   BONO O CAD  BONOBUS ORD. CADIZ  Validación(entrada)
11  2024/04/01  11  93  38  BONO E CAD  BONOBUS ESP. CADIZ  Transbordo(entrada)
12  2024/04/01  11  93  20  BONO E CAD  BONOBUS ESP. CADIZ  Validación(entrada)
13  2024/04/01  11  96  1743    TARJETAS    CONSORCIO MONEDERO  Validación(entrada)
14  2024/04/01  11  Tarifa Gratuita 5   -   CONY. JUB.  Validación(entrada)
15  2024/04/01  11  Tarifa Gratuita 6   -   EMPLEADO    Validación(entrada)
16  2024/04/01  11  Tarifa Gratuita 43  -   FAMILIAR    Validación(entrada)
17  2024/04/01  11  Tarifa Gratuita 4   -   PENSIONISTA Validación(entrada)
18  2024/04/01  11  Tarifa Gratuita 164 MENOR 4AÑO  NULL    Billete
19  2024/04/01  11  Tarifa Gratuita 44  PASE ESP.1  NULL    Billete

Necesito sumar los gratuitos...

Buenas, Juanjo, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Puedes editar la pregunta para incluir el resultado esperado, es decir, has puesto lo que te da actualmente, pero ¿cómo deberían salir esas 6 filas en realidad?

Creo que lo mas sencillo es que utilices una SELECT por encima de la que tienes para agrupar y sumar lo que necesitas.
Usando la segunda SELECT donde ya has agrupado los "gratuitos" que quieres sumar, basta con que agrupes por ese campo.
Suponiendo que la SELECT es esta:
SELECT ...
FORMAT(HoraInicioLinea, 'yyyy/MM/dd') as Fecha,
    linea,...
    ...
    ...
ORDER BY 
    linea ASC

Algo similar a esto:
select T.Tarifa, SUM(T.TotalTarifa) FROM
      (
      SELECT ...
        FORMAT(HoraInicioLinea, 'yyyy/MM/dd') as Fecha,
        linea,...
        ...
        ...
       ORDER BY 
         linea ASC
       ) T
GROUP BY T.Tarifa

Esta te debería devolver un resultado agrupado por el campo Tarifa, y que suma el TotalTarifa de todos ellos.
Tomando los resultados de la primera SELECT como una nueva tabla.
